# Everyone's Problem, nobodies job. or Everyone's Problem, nobody's job

Tags: apostrophe

> Everyone's Problem, nobodies job.

or

> Everyone's Problem, nobody's job

What is the correct use for this sentence?

Comment: The second, obviously. Both parts are using the possessive, which requires an apostrophe.

Comment: _nobodies job_ doesn't even make sense.

Comment: Seems a good question to me - surprising that it is off topic.

Answer (score 1):

Personally I would write this:

> Everyone's problem, nobody's job.

since no *individual* person is responsible for carrying out the job.